# xmlhttp is not defined

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to run this code here, but i keep getting this error

> ReferenceError: xmlHttp is not defined
>       at XMLHttpRequest.ChamadaJSON.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange

I've tried mostly everything but it just continues... Here's the code:

```
function ChamadaJSON(data) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "http://menuetec.esy.es/test3.php?data="+data;
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var responseText = xmlHttp.responseText;
            ConectaServidor(responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    function ConectaServidor(response) {
        var dados = JSON.parse(response);
        var i;
        var conteudo = "";
        var conteudo2 = "";
        var conteudo3 = "";
        var conteudo4 = "";
        for (i = 0; i < dados.length; i++) 
        {
            conteudo += dados[i].tb02_cafe;
            conteudo2 += dados[i].tb02_lanchedia;
            conteudo3 += dados[i].tb02_almoco;
            conteudo4 += dados[i].tb02_lanchenoite;
        }

        document.getElementById("cafe1").innerHTML = conteudo;
        document.getElementById("lanche1").innerHTML = conteudo2;
        document.getElementById("almoco1").innerHTML = conteudo3;
        document.getElementById("lanchen1").innerHTML = conteudo4;
}}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: It's merely a casing issue: `xmlhttp != xmlHttp`

Comment: its a typing mistake its `xmlhttp` the variable you have declared and not `xmlHttp`

Comment: Corrected that, and now I'm getting this ***Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at ConectaServidor (selecionar.js:15)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ChamadaJSON.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange***  :(

Comment: How are you calling `chamadaJSON()`? What's `data`? Right now, loading http://menuetec.esy.es/test3.php?data= without any data results in an empty response from the server.

Comment: `<input type="date" id="data">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="ChamadaJSON(document.getElementById('data').value);">Consultar</button>`

Comment: Can you please give us an example of an actual URL that's working?

Comment: What do you mean @AlejandroIván?

Comment: Load http://menuetec.esy.es/test3.php?data= in your browser. It's empty.

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm new to programming

Comment: @AlejandroIván, could it be a problem with my "url" variable??

Comment: It's not the variable, it's the URL that's not giving you any response. It should give you some text in JSON format but it's giving you no string at all. When you load it in your web browser, it should print something.

Comment: You have used var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); which means it's a block or local variable. Replace this line with xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); When you remove var keyword JavaScript assume it as public variable.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error message, @singhpradeep.

Comment: @Programm0 Can you send actual error message.

Comment: Have you noticed you have declared variable xmlhttp and you are referring xmlHttp at this line of code **var responseText = xmlHttp.responseText;**

Comment: Yayyy! Things worked! The problem was exactly with my url variable, @AlejandroIván... `var url = "http://menuetec.esy.es/test3.php?data='"+data+"'";` (notice the simple quotation marks... that was missing)

Comment: So your URL was `http://menuetec.esy.es/test3.php?data='...'` and not `http://menuetec.esy.es/test3.php?data=...` good you managed to get it working. And you confirmed my suspicions: it was the URL.